# iPhone CSS media queries

Tags: ios, css, html-email

I'm currently developing an HTML email and I've written some media queries for the iPhone as follows:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 6S+, 7+ and 8+ --------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 414px) 
    and (max-device-width : 736px)
    and (orientation : portrait)
    {
        .email-container {
            min-width: 414px !important;
        }
        .email-header{
            padding: 1.2em !important;
        }            
    }
```

Naturally, this media query doesn't get triggered. :-)

Instead, when I add the following styling to the head, it affects the HTML:

```
/* Nexus 5X, Nexus 6, Nexus 6P, Pixel, Pixel XL, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL*/
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 411px) 
    and (max-device-width : 731px)        
    and (orientation : portrait)
    {
        .email-container {
            min-width: 411px !important;
        }

        .email-header{
            padding: 1.2em !important;
        }            
    }
```

From what I understand and based on a bit of research, [link](https://mydevice.io/devices/#sortTablets), [link](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions), the device dimensions for the iPhone 6+,6S+, 7+ are 414px X 736px.

Why are the media queries for 411px X 731px devices getting triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the widths and heights mixed a little. Try the below code

```
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 414px) 
    and (max-height : 736px)
    {
        .email-container {
            min-width: 414px !important;
        }
        .email-header{
            padding: 1.2em !important;
        }            
    }
```

The code looks for a max device width and **max device height** now with orientation as portrait. Which is what your research brought up:

> From what I understand and based on a bit of research, link, link, the
>   device dimensions for the iPhone 6+,6S+, 7+ are 414px X 736px.

Hope this answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying Syfer! That definitely moves me in the right direction... :-)

The snippet you provided works for 6+ tec but interferes with 6/6S.

Comment: I've tried a few mods here: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/manavecplan/8301c9672051aa93c1d7be4f89d0dd53) but the logic of it is starting to to slip away

Comment: Your original question had issue which I have fixed and yes it will work in 6+ and not on bigger screen sizes. Reason being you are restricting to a specific device with that dimensions. I use only max width 480 and cater for others as issues start occurring

Comment: I have updated the code above. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Syfer!